# Heroku app successfully deploying, but receiving application error when loading site

Tags: python, django, heroku

My logs don't indicate any errors as far as I can tell, but I'm receiving the following error when loading the site:

`An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. If you are the application owner, check your logs for details. You can do this from the Heroku CLI with the command
heroku logs --tail`

Below you can find the logs. Am I missing something here?

```
-----> Python app detected
-----> Uninstalling stale dependencies
       Uninstalling Django-2.1.5:
         Successfully uninstalled Django-2.1.5
       Uninstalling Pillow-5.4.1:
         Successfully uninstalled Pillow-5.4.1
-----> Installing requirements with pip
       Collecting dj-database-url==0.5.0 (from -r /tmp/build_99fe21a8dcc00005ce600053adc20260/requirements.txt (line 1))
         Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d4/a6/4b8578c1848690d0c307c7c0596af2077536c9ef2a04d42b00fabaa7e49d/dj_database_url-0.5.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
       Collecting Django==2.1.5 (from -r /tmp/build_99fe21a8dcc00005ce600053adc20260/requirements.txt (line 2))
         Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/36/50/078a42b4e9bedb94efd3e0278c0eb71650ed9672cdc91bd5542953bec17f/Django-2.1.5-py3-none-any.whl (7.3MB)
       Collecting django-heroku==0.3.1 (from -r /tmp/build_99fe21a8dcc00005ce600053adc20260/requirements.txt (line 3))
         Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/59/af/5475a876c5addd5a3494db47d9f7be93cc14d3a7603542b194572791b6c6/django_heroku-0.3.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
       Collecting gunicorn==19.9.0 (from -r /tmp/build_99fe21a8dcc00005ce600053adc20260/requirements.txt (line 4))
         Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/8c/da/b8dd8deb741bff556db53902d4706774c8e1e67265f69528c14c003644e6/gunicorn-19.9.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (112kB)
       Collecting Pillow==5.4.1 (from -r /tmp/build_99fe21a8dcc00005ce600053adc20260/requirements.txt (line 5))
         Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ae/2a/0a0ab2833e5270664fb5fae590717f867ac6319b124160c09f1d3291de28/Pillow-5.4.1-cp37-cp37m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (2.0MB)
       Collecting psycopg2==2.8.2 (from -r /tmp/build_99fe21a8dcc00005ce600053adc20260/requirements.txt (line 6))
         Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/23/7e/93c325482c328619870b6cd09370f6dbe1148283daca65115cd63642e60f/psycopg2-2.8.2.tar.gz (368kB)
       Collecting whitenoise==4.1.2 (from -r /tmp/build_99fe21a8dcc00005ce600053adc20260/requirements.txt (line 8))
         Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/fd/2a/b51377ab9826f0551da19951257d2434f46329cd6cfdf9592ea9ca5f6034/whitenoise-4.1.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
       Installing collected packages: dj-database-url, Django, whitenoise, psycopg2, django-heroku, gunicorn, Pillow
         Running setup.py install for psycopg2: started
           Running setup.py install for psycopg2: finished with status 'done'
       Successfully installed Django-2.1.5 Pillow-5.4.1 dj-database-url-0.5.0 django-heroku-0.3.1 gunicorn-19.9.0 psycopg2-2.8.2 whitenoise-4.1.2
-----> $ python manage.py collectstatic --noinput
       119 static files copied to '/tmp/build_99fe21a8dcc00005ce600053adc20260/staticfiles', 375 post-processed.
-----> Discovering process types
 ~     Mis-cased procfile detected; ignoring.
 ~     Rename it to Procfile to have it honored.
       Procfile declares types -> (none)
-----> Compressing...
       Done: 68.2M
-----> Launching...
       Released v7
       https://andrew-data-incubator-project.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
```

Comment: What's the output of `heroku --logs tail --app <your-app>`?

Comment: @Alex I've added the output of that as an edit.

Comment: There was a typo in my suggestion. The right command is: `heroku logs --tail  --app <your-app>`

Comment: write this command to see your error in the terminal `heroku logs --tail --app your_app_name`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
 ~     Mis-cased procfile detected; ignoring.
 ~     Rename it to Procfile to have it honored.
```

Try renaming `procfile` to `Procfile` as the message in the logs suggests.

Comment: Good catch! That got rid of that message in the log, but I'm still getting that error. I've updated my post with the new error log.

Comment: Please don’t rewrite your question with a completely new error - it means that existing answers don’t make sense any more. I’ve rolled back the question to an earlier version.

Comment: The second error is because you used an invalid module name `data-incubator-project.wsgi`, perhaps in Procfile. Python module names can’t contain hyphens. Perhaps you want `data_incubation_project.wsgi`, but I can’t tell for sure because you didn’t show your project layout.

Answer (score 1):

Try Manual Deployment again and the error will resolve.
Actually it's a temporary solution as this error will again arise after sometime.

Comment: how to fix this issue permanently?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have added `const port = Process.env.PORT || 3000 ;` in your app and remove the localhost if you have mentioned while listening at the port .

```
server.listen(port,()=>{  // do not add localhost here if you are deploying it
    console.log("server listening to port "+port);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `web:node server.js`
Not space `web: node server.js`
in ProcFile